# composer does not download twitter/bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php

I have problem with downloading twitter/bootstrap package v2.2.2 from packagist by composer.

The error message is after trying to download the package:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]  The
>   "https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/v2.2.2" file
>   co  uld not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

It's a little weird because the version really exists. I'm using composer on windows and I have never had such a problem yet.

Comment: Run `composer diag` and see what it outputs. Maybe Github was down for a moment.

Comment: https://status.github.com/messages "We've mitigated the DDoS attack and the site should responding normally. We're still investigating the cause of the small increase in exceptions when accessing the GitHub API."

Comment: really thanks, perhaps then everything return to normal:)

Comment: the problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the following JSON in my composer.lock file:

```
 {
        "name": "twbs/bootstrap",
        "version": "v2.2.2",
        "target-dir": "twbs/bootstrap",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git",
            "reference": "v2.2.2"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v2.3.2.zip",
            "reference": "v2.2.2",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "type": "library",
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "Apache-2.0"
        ],
        "description": "Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.",
        "homepage": "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/",
        "keywords": [
            "bootstrap",
            "css"
        ],
        "time": "2012-12-08 20:57:21"
    }
```

Replaced all "twitter" with twbs. I suspect you can change the version to be 2.3.2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Bootstrap 3 they have changed the URLs a bit.

the path changes from twitter/bootstrap to twbs/bootstrap

As of right now when I write this, the new path is pulling 2.3.2 but I suspect it will soon begin pulling 3.x.

More info here: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/07/27/bootstrap-3-rc1/

Comment: Way to break a lot of peoples dependencies! Also note; `twitter/bootstrap-custompath` is no longer.